# What is the font used in some (presumably) LaTeX papers?

Tags: font-identification, latex, serif

I was wondering, what kind of font is being used in some LaTeX papers such as this one [https://www.mscs.dal.ca/~selinger/3343/handouts/ideals.pdf](https://www.mscs.dal.ca/%7Eselinger/3343/handouts/ideals.pdf) or this [http://www.math.rwth-aachen.de/~Max.Neunhoeffer/Teaching/ff/ffchap3.pdf](http://www.math.rwth-aachen.de/%7EMax.Neunhoeffer/Teaching/ff/ffchap3.pdf).

[image]

[image]

I tried few different font matchers, (whathefont, identifont, whatfontis, fontsprint matcherator), and the closest one I got was PT Serif Mono or Cordale.

I think it might be Cordale, but I'm not sure where it really is, especially since I can't found any resources talking about it (and its usage in LaTeX) outside of type foundries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The middle stem of `m` and the descender of `y` are quite distinctive. It's probably Noto Serif Semicondensed, or perhaps some variety of Droid Serif

[image: Noto Serif Semicondensed]

[image: Droid Serif]

Comment: It looks like it's some variation of Noto Serif, probably Condensed or SemiCondensed. Nevertheless, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Since you have access to the PDF, you can find out the font names yourself, without guessing.

1. Open the PDF in Adobe Acrobat Reader (this is free software available from Adobe).
2. Right click anywhere on the document, and choose Document Properties
3. Select the Fonts Tab, and all the fonts used will be listed.

Comment: Sadly, Adobe Acrobat Reader doesn't support Linux anymore, the latest version they provide is for 32-bit operating systems, and I don't really feel like fiddling with Wine to make it work properly. Thanks for answer nonetheless!

Comment: @Leyla Maybe some other PDF viewer then?  There are bound to be some available for Linux.

Answer (score 0):

I've examined the pdf metadata using Adobe Reader on macOS and the fonts used are Times (the Linotype release of Times New Roman), plus various CMM fonts for the math content. *All* the body text is in Times.

I wonder if your viewer on Linux is having some problems loading the fonts? Your screenshots definitely show Noto Serif (or possibly Droid Serif, which has the same Latin-alphabet characters, but no native condensed styles), perhaps being used as fallback? I don't know what pdf reader you're using but if you're on Linux I imagine it's likely an open-source pdf viewer which would very likely have open-source Noto/Droid fonts as fallback. We see here a common sign of a fallback font, condensed or stretched text caused by needing to scrunch the fallback font into a different font's metrics. That's happened here, but I'm not entirely sure *why*, since Times has fairly normal proportions. Maybe its vertical height is higher than Noto's or something. Anyhow, I guess the fun thing is this font is already on your computer somewhere inside the pdf program and you just need to get it out.

In the finite field pdf as I see it text in italic isn't in a real italic font, by the way, it's simply the roman slanted to the right. This is the standard action when an italic font can't be found, although I don't know exactly how this works in TeX. So there could be glitches in the pdf production.